# Sphinx: Putting a code segment at the first line of an unordered list item

Tags: python, restructuredtext, python-sphinx

I'm using Sphinx to manage my project's documentation.

I have an unordered list, and I want the first line of every item to be a code segment. (Not inline, a paragraph.)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at my own documentation I found a similar scenario, however I can't guarantee that it will work with the documentation as the *first* text in the list:

```
#.  **Defining the Model Class**

    All models must inherit from |LrbBaseModel| either directly or
    indirectly and have the |LrbModelInit| decorator above their
    constructor (a.k.a. ``__init__``)::

        class foo(LrbBaseModel):
            @LrbModelInit()
            def __init__(self):
                ...
```

This produces:

[image]

I think you can get away with a code block without pre-amble text like the following:

```
#.  ::
        def fooDeFaFa():
            pass
```

Notice that my code block is indented twice.  The `::` indicates the empty textual paragraph block, and then my code is a child of this `::` syntax via indenting a second time.

Alternatively, this may work:

```
#.
    ::
        def fooDeFaFa():
            pass
```

Comment: `#. ::` will work perfectly; inside the list item it's just a perfectly ordinary paragraph, so the `::` will work as expected. Try it at http://www.tele3.cz/jbar/rest/rest.html for simplicity. Note though that he did say unordered - `* ::` or `- ::` would have been more accurate for this reason.